# Vertically centered: Parent element with 2 child elements

Tags: css

Please have a look at this code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <header class="child-1">
    <h1 class="float-left">lorem...</h1>
    <div class="float-right">lorem...</div>
  </header>
  <div class="child-2">lorem...</div>
</div>
```

CSS looks like:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Applying this causes both child-1 and child-2 centered vertically in one line. I need that child-2 should start from line2, i.e., right below child-1.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `flex-direction`:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <header class="child-1">
    <h1 class="float-left">lorem...</h1>
    <div class="float-right">lorem...</div>
  </header>
  <div class="child-2">lorem...</div>
</div>
```

Then you probably want to adjust the `align-items` as I'm assuming you don't actually want to center everything horizontally.

Comment: Setting flex-direction: column helps somewhat, but issue is that child-2 is dynamic, some time it appears in markup some times not. In case it appears then styling works as expected,  but in case it doesn’t then child-1 is no more vertically centered

Comment: Edited. You need to set `justify-content` to adjust the vertical alignment of a flex column.

Comment: Thanks, it solves the issue. Thanks a lot. But without height: 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Would be great if you add some comments to your answer to help other people to understand it. One of the main purpose of this site is to learn from each other.

Comment: Thank your suggestion, my english is poor. I'm trying to improve my english skill.